# Not able to do an HTTP request to sign up a new user in Cognito AWS with Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-cognito

I am trying to do a manual request of a sign up with Postman.
There is a POST request with the header:

```
Content-Type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
X-Amz-Target:AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.SignUp
```

and the body in raw look like this:

```
{
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "Password": "xxxxxxxx",
    "UserAttributes": [ 
                        {
                            "Name": "Name",
                            "Value": "xxxxxx@dd.com"
                        }
                    ],
    "Username": "xxxxxxx"
}
```

I am getting, in the response this error:

```
{"__type":"UnknownOperationException"}
```

Any clue why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please reference [cognito API - AdminCreateUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html)

So the json data should be:

```
{
   "DesiredDeliveryMediums": [ "string" ],
   "ForceAliasCreation": boolean,
   "MessageAction": "string",
   "TemporaryPassword": "string",
   "UserAttributes": [ 
      { 
         "Name": "string",
         "Value": "string"
      }
   ],
   "Username": "string",
   "UserPoolId": "string",
   "ValidationData": [ 
      { 
         "Name": "string",
         "Value": "string"
      }
   ]
}
```

There is no `ClientId`

Comment: the problem was the camel case i was putting Signup